# Script to automatically rotate and scale portrait

Tags: imagemagick

I am basically trying to display a bunch of portrait/landscape pictures. It works just fine with landscape on the screen, however portrait pictures are unfortunately cropped by the display software.

What I am trying to do is to develop a script which,
a.) detects all portrait pictures
b.) converts them (with e.g., black stripes on the side) to landscape  by keeping  the properties.

I already tried the hints in [ImageMagick resize - set width for both landscape and portrait images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25557479/imagemagick-resize-set-width-for-both-landscape-and-portrait-images)
but did not really get a solution.

Any hints?

Answer (score 1):

Using ImageMagick from the command line, this command will read the input image and pad the left and right with black to make it square if it's portrait orientation. It will leave it as-is if it's already square or landscape. In *nix syntax...

```
convert input.png -virtual-pixel black \
   -set option:distort:viewport "%[fx:w<h?h:w]x%[h]" \
   -distort affine "0,0 %[fx:w<h?(h-w)/2:0],0" result.png
```

For Windows you would need to replace those end-of-line backslashes "\" with carets "^", or just make the command into a single line.

If you're using IM version 7 you should use "magick" instead of "convert".